# Why is it important to implement __get__ method in a descriptor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class BoundedNumber:
    def __init__(self, min_val, max_val):
        self.min_val = min_val
        self.max_val = max_val

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
    

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self.min_val > value or value > self.max_val:
            msg = '{} takes values between {} and {}'.format(
                self.name, 
                self.min_val, 
                self.max_val,
            )
            raise ValueError(msg)
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

class Person:
    age = BoundedNumber(1, 120)
    weight = BoundedNumber(1, 250)
    height = BoundedNumber(1, 230)

    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, height):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
p1 = Person('Shiva',5,45,179)
print(p1.age)
print(Person.age)
```

On running this code snippet, I am getting the same output as I will get if I write a `__get__` method in the descriptor class so what is the significance of writing a `__get__` method in the descriptor class?

Comment: It's not important unless you need different behavior. The [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) explain this pretty well:  *"A descriptor can define any combination of __get__(), __set__() and __delete__(). If it does not define __get__(), then accessing the attribute will return the descriptor object itself unless there is a value in the object’s instance dictionary."*

Comment: the significance of `__get__` is you can define a different name for a value, such as an attribute prefixed by an underscore (a private name). But I agree in this case you can probably omit it without any noticeable change.

Comment: @Mark your comment explains the behavior that is expected if I do not define a __get__ method but it says nothing about the significance of why I should implement a __get__ method in my descriptor class.

Comment: @madur as the docs say you `"can define any combination of"`. Nowhere does it say you *should* define any of these that you don't need. So obviously it's not going to say *why* you should. If you are looking for use cases of `__get__`, checkout the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

Comment: Is the `__get__` important? Who said that? There is no need to define `__get__` in this example, so it is not important here.

Comment: descriptor class is BoundedNumber ????